# Attach new key and value by matching collection value

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

Hello great people of SO!

First of all, I'm sorry if my english is not very good, but I'm gonna try my best here to describe my problem

I have 3 Models

1. User
2. Post
3. Like

> User.php

```
___________________________________________________________
| id  | name | email | password | created_at | updated_at |
| ... | ...  | ...   | ...      | ...        | ...        |
| ... | ...  | ...   | ...      | ...        | ...        |
| ... | ...  | ...   | ...      | ...        | ...        |

User model relationship:

public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

> Post.php

```
__________________________________________________
| id  | user_id | body | created_at | updated_at |
| ... | ...     | ...  | ...        | ...        |
| ... | ...     | ...  | ...        | ...        |

Post model relationship:

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function likes() {
    return $this->morphMany('likeable');
}
```

> Like.php

```
_________________________________________________________________________
| id  | likeable_type | likeable_id | user_id | created_at | updated_at |
| ... | ...           | ...         | ...     | ...        | ...        |
| ... | ...           | ...         | ...     | ...        | ...        |
| ... | ...           | ...         | ...     | ...        | ...        |

Like model relationship:

public function likeable() {
    return $this->morphTo('likeable');
}
```

Everything works fine, for simple C.R.U.D

The problem comes when I use [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar),
I saw so many repetitive queries just to fetch few records:

```
Ex:
    // Let say that I have 5 users
    $users = User::all();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->load('posts');
    }

    return $users;

    // Result
    select * from `posts`.`user_id` 1 ...
    select * from `posts`.`user_id` 2 ...
    select * from `posts`.`user_id` 3 ...
```

> So I decide to change the method

```
Ex:
    $users = User::all();

    $posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();

    // Result:
    select * `posts`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I no longer see repetitive query, which is good,
After solving this repetitive query, I fetch 'likes' from specific posts

```
Ex:
    $users = User::all();

    $posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();

    $posts_likes = Like::where('likeable_type', 'App\Post') // morphMany
                ->whereIn('likeable_id', $posts->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();
```

Now here's the problems, I do not know how to pair posts_likes to to it's post

```
Ex:
    $posts = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'user_id': 2,
            'body': 'Lorem ipsum...',
            ...
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'user_id': 2,
            'body': 'Sit amet...',
            ...
        },
        {
            'id': 3,
            'user_id': 3,
            'body': 'abcde...',
            ...    
        },
        ... etc
    ];

    $posts_likes = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'likeable_type': 'App\Post',
            'likeable_id': 2,
            'user_id': 3,
            ...
        },
            'id': 2,
            'likeable_type': 'App\Post',
            'likeable_id': 2,
            'user_id': 2,
            ...
        {
            'id': 3,
            'likeable_type': 'App\Post',
            'likeable_id': 1,
            'user_id': 5,
            ...
        },
        {
            'id': 4,
            'likeable_type': 'App\Post',
            'likeable_id': 3,
            'user_id': 1,
            ...
        },
        ... etc
    ];
```

**My question:**

How to insert likes inside $posts collection by matching exact id? (post id == like likeable_id)

So I can access them in loop, like: $post->likes = [...]

```
Ex:
    $posts = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'user_id': 2,
            'body': 'Lorem ipsum...',
            'likes': [
                // All likes for post with this id (1)
            ],
            ...
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'user_id': 2,
            'body': 'Sit amet...',
            'likes': [
                // All likes for post with this id (2)
            ],
            ...
        },
        ...
    ];
```

If there's any unclear explanation, I will edit it a.s.a.p
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can eagar load all of them

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading

```php
$users = User::with('posts.likes')->get();
return $users;
```

this code will work if you set correct relationship

```php
//user model
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

//post model
public function likes()
{
    return $this->morphMany('likeable');
}
```

i suppose to generate json link

```json
[{
    "name": "user",
    "posts": [{
            "name": "postName",
            "likes": []
        },
        {
            "name": "postName",
            "likes": []
        }
    ]
}]
```